# Keep ThreeJs sprite looking at Mapbox camera

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js

How can I keep my sprites facing the Mapbox gl camera?

To do this, I assume I need access to the Mapbox camera position - however, I don't know how to access this from inside the Three.js scene.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include the minimal reproducible code.